# Animate(transformX): Is it possible to vanish a div after it reaches the corner of parent div

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, transform

I have an animation to slide and fade out a div element.
Is there any possibility to let the div vanish, after it reaches its parent div corner, like its the end of the screen, so its not moved outside the "box"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: Are you setting the css animation class with javascript? If so you can `setTimeout` passing the animation time and  `remove` the div in the callback